# Getting private files or showing private images in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder how to publishing **private user files** but in the way only that user can access it. I mean, after logging in, there would be many files that only the user logged in can access. For instance, an image collection or maybe a mp3 file to play in a html5 player or a pdf to download. But the point is the user logged is the owner of the files and he is the only one who can get them.

My problem is that in the HTML code I need to provide a link in the image attribute or a link in the html5 mp3 player or a file link to download it. And this link has to be pointing to a public directory so it can be accessed by everybody.

My question is: how do people implement that kind of security or functionality nowadays?

Another example. In facebook, you have your own private images and even if you give the full link of any private image to a friend, he cannot see it unless you tag that image as "public" or something like that.

### Possible solution

I have been researching about the ideas people have given me here. I did try some things; for instance, I went to Facebook and got the link of a private image of mine (by right clicking over and copy image link...) I put that link in other browser and after logging out of Facebook, and I can see the image in the browser so the conclusion is the file has to be public in the moment we access. Other thing is we hide the name file or something like that.

I propose to:

- Users file has to be in a folder which has a "unique reference" as name that only can know the own user. So by storing this reference in a database like a password ... you got the idea...
- Sometimes, we will need to have "public files" with limited access, I mean, I want to people to play a mp3 in the html5 player or a video, but I don't want to let them to download it. In this cases, we could obfuscate the code making it hard to find the full link.

Comment: This is a very broad subject that cannot be covered here, I'm afraid. There are many, many ways to achive this. Doing it server side would be best as JavaScript could always be tinkered with by a visitor.

Comment: What I find the most secure option is saving user files outside the document root. However, to accomplish this, you need full access to your server. By default, php cannot traverse outside of the document root. So you need to do some tweaking to allow this. Once done, there simply aren't any direct links to the files that will work. Php itself however can access them and return them to the user.

Comment: Thanks very much Darren H , do you know any resource or tutorial covering this problem? I DON'T FIND GOOGLING :-(

Comment: Hi icecub, thanks:
You mean the request contain the file itself istead of provide a link to the "public file" ? So, I like that, but how can I tell to htm5 to load for example and image or to play an mp3 file in the html5 player?? Because As far as I know it need a link to the resourse!!

Comment: It took me a moment to find it, but I think you'll find this PDF a very interesting read for what you'll need: [Secure file upload in PHP web applications](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/164.pdf) It covers reading them as well.

Comment: As for your question, I'm afraid it gets very complicated to do such things. Just thinking out loud, I'd say using Ajax to make php push the file back to the html output. Not sure if something like that will work though. I've certainly never tried it. Another idea would be to make php copy the file to a temporary publicly accessable folder and delete after a session expires or something. I have to say your issue is quite interesting. Might have a go at something like that myself.

Comment: Thanks again icecub, It was really helpfull, I'm going to comment some conclutions at the top I got after to make any tries to help anyone

Comment: I'm currently working on some kind of script that does what you want. I'm not sure if I'll succeed yet, as I'm facing quite a lot of challanges. But that's exactly why I find these kind of questions interesting! They're challanging my intellect, haha.

Comment: Hahaha, that's really cool! I'm looking for see what you're getting!!

Comment: Almost got it working. Just the final touch is bugging me at the moment. So far: `secure upload = check`, `file publicly unaccessable = check`, `no root needed = check`, `file send back to html5 = check` Last issue: Struggling with the content types. Html5 refuses to recognise them for the moment.

Comment: Woohoo! Got it working! Now I just have to adjust it completely to what you need. Answer is coming soon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. Since I'm unformilliar with your code, I'm going to use a bit of general code as an example. All you have to do is adjust it.

First a very basic html that will upload the video / mp3 / image or whatever:

```
<form name="upload" action="" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    Select the file to upload: <input type="file" name="userfile">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
</form>
```

Next you need to prepare your database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `original_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `mime_type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now comes the file upload part. At this point I should mention that I'm not very well formilliar with MySQLi. Therefor I'm using PDO in this example. You should however be able to adjust it to MySQLi if you prefer:

```
<?php
session_start();
# My PDO class. A link to it can be found at the bottom of this answer
require_once 'pdo.class.php';

# Send user back login if not logged
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_login_userid_here'])){
    Header("Location: your_login.php");
}

# If file is uploaded
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $uploaddir = 'uploads'; # Your upload directory

    function tempnam_sfx($path, $suffix){
        do {
            $file = $path."/".mt_rand().$suffix;
            $fp = @fopen($file, 'x');
        }
        while(!$fp);

        fclose($fp);
        return $file;
    }

    # Make a regular expression to check for allowed mime types
    $pattern = "#^(image/|video/|audio/)[^\s\n<]+$#i";

    if(!preg_match($pattern, $_FILES['userfile']['type']){
        die("Only image, video and audio files are allowed!");
    }

    $uploadfile = tempnam_sfx($uploaddir, ".tmp");

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

        # Define db configuration
        define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
        define("DB_USER", "username");
        define("DB_PASS", "password");
        define("DB_NAME", "dbname");

        $db = new Database;

        $db->query("INSERT INTO uploads SET userid=:id, name=:filename, original_name=:oriname, mime_type=:mime");

        $db->bind(":userid",$_SESSION['your_login_userid_here']);
        $db->bind(":filename",basename($uploadfile));
        $db->bind(":oriname",basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
        $db->bind(":mime",$_FILES['userfile']['type']);

        try {
            $db->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            unlink($uploadfile);

            die("Error saving data to the database. The file was not uploaded");
        }

        $id = $db->lastInsertId();
        echo "File succesfully uploaded.\n";

    } else {
        echo "File uploading failed.\n";
    }
} else {
    # No upload received. Send user to upload page
    Header("Location: html_upload_form.html");
}

?>
```

So what is happening? Basicly we are uploading the file to our upload dir where we give it a random filename with the `.tmp` extension. In our database we're saving this random filename, the original filename, and what type of file it is. Ofcourse we're adding the userid as well so we know to whom to file belongs. The benefits of this approach are as follows:

- - No one will ever know the file name on the server.
- - No one will ever know the original file name except the owner.
- - The Mime Type allows us to setup our HTML5 mediaplayer.
- - The owner is able to download the file, but no one else.

Up comes the PHP file that will retrieve the uploaded file for us:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'pdo.class.php';

# Send user back login if not logged
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_login_session_here'])){
    Header("Location: your_login.php");
}

# Define db configuration
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "username");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "dbname");

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(!is_numeric($id)) {
   die("File id must be numeric");
}

$db = new Database;

$db->query('SELECT userid, name, mime_type FROM uploads WHERE id=:id');

$db->bind(":id", $id);

try {
    $file = $db->single();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error fetching data from the database");
}

# Check if file belongs to user
if($_SESSION['your_login_session_here'] != $file['userid']){
    die("This file does not belong to you!");
}

if(is_null($file) || count($file)==0) {
    die("File not found");
}

$newfile = $file['original_name']; # The original filename

# Send headers and file back
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($newfile));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($uploaddir.$file['name']));
header("Content-Type: " . $file['mime_type']);
readfile($uploaddir.$file['name']);

?>
```

What is happening? In this file, you're using the file id to retrieve the users file from the database. That way no user needs to know any filename at all! Thanks to our headers, the owner of the file will however be able to download the file with it's original name, without knowing the filename on the server at all.

So next I will give you a short example on how to show the user all his files:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'pdo.class.php';

# Send user back login if not logged
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_login_session_here'])){
    Header("Location: your_login.php");
}

# Define db configuration
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "username");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "dbname");

$db = new Database;

# Retrieve all files from the user and build links
$db->query("SELECT id, original_name, mime_type FROM uploads WHERE userid=:id");

$db->bind(":id",$_SESSION['your_login_session_here']);

try {
    $files = $db->resultset();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error fetching data from the database");
}

if($db->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($files as $file){
        echo "<a href='your_html_viewer_file.php?id=". $file['id'] "&type=". $file['mime_type'] .">". $file['original_name'] ."</a><br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "No files found!";
}

?>
```

And finally comes the PHP file that will display the file in some HTML mediaplayer. I will only 2 examples here, you should be able add your own very easily:

```
<?php
session_start();

# Send user back login if not logged
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_login_session_here'])){
    Header("Location: your_login.php");
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$type = $_GET['type'];

if(strpos($type, 'video/') === 0){ ?>

    <video width="480" height="320" controls>
        <source src="your_file_retriever.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" type="<?php echo $type; ?>">
    </video>

<?php } else if(strpos($type, 'audio/') === 0){ ?>

    <audio controls>
        <source src="your_file_retriever.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" type="<?php echo $type; ?>">
    </audio>

<?php } ?>
```

Now to make sure no one is going to just brute force attack your uploads folder, you need to create a .htaccess file inside this folder. The following code will block anyone from accessing that folder except the server itself ofcourse:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

My [PDO Class](http://pastebin.com/FJT526me).

Comment: @user2992476 Thanks for your appreciation. Let me know if any issues arise and I'll do my best to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions.  The one I am using for a dating site is to have folder names that are the same as the unique reference for the user.  All files in there belong to that user.  However access is still controlled by php providing the correct links in the html.

That is the simplified answer.  because I don't want the number of sub-folders in the image folder to be in the thousands, I hash them into another level of folders.

Comment: THanks very much Rohit Gupta, so, In your solution the point is that only the user-owner knows the unique reference (folder name), so the files are still public and the unique reference works like a "private key" isn't it?

Comment: In my usage the files are all read only and anyone is allowed to see them.  If the user wants to edit or replace them then this happens via a new temporary random-named folder.  In your case, the above answers the storage issue.  You still have to sort out the security to suit.