# Accept uploaded files with the same name?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, file-upload

I Have a form where people can upload a single image. Most people are uploading pictures from their mobile devices. Everyone with an iPhone, has their image uploaded as "image.png". I need to have my form not reject it, and just accept files with the same name without delete the old one or rename them something like "imageupload1.png", "imageupload2.png" or even image.png then "image-Copy.png" then "image-Copy(2).png", etc

I figure something like this might work:

```
$filename = $_FILES['myfilename']['name'];
$filename = time().$filename;
```

or

```
 function renameDuplicates($path, $file)
{   
    $fileName = pathinfo($path . $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $fileExtension = "." . pathinfo($path . $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $returnValue = $fileName . $fileExtension;

    $copy = 1;
    while(file_exists($path . $returnValue))
    {
        $returnValue = $fileName . '-copy-'. $copy . $fileExtension;
        $copy++;
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "Sucessfully Uploaded - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

I just don't know where to plug it in. I'm a noob so take it easy on me and please be specific. The options I "figured might work" were taken from other questions but they didn't work for me, chances are i'm doing something wrong so please don't mark this as "already asked" Thank you. Sorry for the bother.

```js
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "<a href='../pie.html' style='border: 5px solid #3a57af;padding-right:50px;padding-bottom:25px;padding-left:50px;display:inline;font-weight:bold;color:#3a57af';> CLICK HERE TO REGISTER</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

```css
html {
   padding-top: 5em;
   font-family: trebuchet, sans-serif;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: bold;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   text-align: center;
   background: white;
}

body { 
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
 text-align:center;
}
div.imageupload {
 padding: 5em 5em 5em 5em;
 height:100vh;
 width:100vh;
 text-align:justify
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Submission</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/image.css">
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="imageupload">
<p><h1>Step 1</h1><br>
Please submit a recent photograph to be featured on the homepage of this website.<br><br>
We will place your yearbook picture in the lower right hand corner of the image you submit.<br>
<br>This will allow our classmates to see how we look now and how we looked then.<br><br>
Please select an appropriate image for a website of this nature. <br><br>
The image should show you from your head to at least your knees. <br><br>
The image should not be a group picture, please be the only one in the picture.<br><br> 
Any pictures that do not meet this criteria will be sent back and will not be posted.<br></p>
<form action="PHPmailer/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Normally you just create a temporary name for uploaded files. But working with scripts that allow visitors to upload files can be a huge security risk if you don't know what you're doing. Take a look at my answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410732/gettings-private-files-or-showing-private-images-in-a-html-page/32412736#32412736). It deals with most security issues as well as unique names yet still being able to return the original filename to whoever visits the image / video etc.

Comment: @icecub ok cool thanks I'll check it out. The purpose of the file upload is to have my old classmates upload a picture of themselves to be featured on our 10 year reunion website. So the original file names aren't really important as i'm individually placing the images elsewhere. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `$target_file` definition, plug in your dedup function:

```
$target_file = renameDuplicates($target_dir, basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
```

(I did not check whether the function behaves properly, but at the first glance it should be all right.)

EDIT: The function was a tiny bit broken.

```
function renameDuplicates($path, $file) {   
    $fileName = pathinfo($path . $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $fileExtension = "." . pathinfo($path . $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $returnValue = $path . $fileName . $fileExtension;

    $copy = 1;
    while(file_exists($returnValue))
    {
        $returnValue = $path . $fileName . '-copy-'. $copy . $fileExtension;
        $copy++;
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Check the lines containing `$returnValue` for changes.

Comment: Im going to try this. Thanks

Comment: Then the function has an error, I suppose. Which fatal error, and on which line?

Comment: line 3 i changed "$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);"  to "$target_file = renameDuplicates($target_dir, basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));"

Comment: That was not my question. Which error did PHP report? At which line did it report it?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function renameDuplicates() in /../../../../../uploads.php on line 3

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: you did not actually put the function from your question into your code.

Comment: From my original question: "I just don't know where to plug it in. I'm a noob so take it easy on me and please be specific. The options I "figured might work" were taken from other questions but they didn't work for me, chances are i'm doing something wrong so please don't mark this as "already asked" Thank you. Sorry for the bother." .... What you deem "self explanatory" has me stuck. You are under no obligation to provide me with an answer, but, that answer, which I assume you have, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just put the first half of the `renameDuplicate` snippet (`function renameDuplicates($path, $file) { ... return $returnValue; }`) into your script; just below `<?php` would be fine. Then the function should be available for the changed line to work.

Comment: Ok I did that but I guess the renaming process is some how it is throwing off the file type. Because i'm getting a "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed" and i've tried to upload 2 of every type of image.

Comment: Check what the result is: insert temporarily `echo "original: ". $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]."; dedup: ".$target_file."\n";` after the `$target_file = ...` line.

Comment: That's weird. I did that and the file uploaded outside of the "uploads" folder

Comment: And it still does not rename same-name files, it tells me that the file name already exist and file was not uploaded.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot help you if you do not report the results of debugging statements.

Comment: Oh sorry lol. "original: 001.png; dedup: 001.png You selected a - image/png."

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the function (it is edited into my answer). You can remove the diagnostic `echo` line now.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to your rescue, and written the whole thing for you :)

You will need to have this structure:

```
upload.php
ImageUpload/uploadMe.php
```

**in upload.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Your image here | SiteName</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            $FLAG = $_GET['e'];

            if($FLAG == "UPLOAD_FAILED"){ ?>
            <div class="col-md-12 alert alert-warning">
                Ooops! It looks like an error occured when uploading your image.
            </div>
            <?php } else if($FLAG == "NOT_IMAGE"){ ?>
            <div class="col-md-12 alert alert-warning">
                Hey! Thats not an image?<br/>
                <pre>We only allow: png, jpg, gif and jpeg images.</pre>
            </div>
            <?php } else{} ?> 
            <div class="well col-md-6">
                <form action="ImageUpload/uploadMe.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <legend>
                        Image Upload
                    </legend>

                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control btn btn-info"/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="well col-md-6">
                <p><h1>Step 1</h1><br>
Please submit a recent photograph to be featured on the homepage of this website.<br><br>
We will place your yearbook picture in the lower right hand corner of the image you submit.<br>
<br>This will allow our classmates to see how we look now and how we looked then.<br><br>
Please select an appropriate image for a website of this nature. <br><br>
The image should show you from your head to at least your knees. <br><br>
The image should not be a group picture, please be the only one in the picture.<br><br> 
Any pictures that do not meet this criteria will be sent back and will not be posted.<br></p>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**In ImageUpload/uploadMe.php:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

$File = $_FILES['file'];


//File properties:
$FileName = $File['name'];
$TmpLocation = $File['tmp_name'];
$FileSize = $File['size'];
$FileError = $File['error'];


//Figure out what kind of file this is:
$FileExt = explode('.', $FileName);
$FileExt = strtolower(end($FileExt));


//Allowed files:
$Allowed = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');

//Check if file is allowed:
if(in_array($FileExt, $Allowed)){

    //Does it return an error ?
    //No:
    if($FileError==0){

        $ImageFolder = "uploads";

        //Check if exist, otherwise create it!
        if (!is_dir($ImageFolder)) {
        mkdir($ImageFolder, 0777, true); 
        }
        else{}


        //Create new filename:
        $NewName = uniqid('', true) . rand(123456789,987654321). '.' . $FileExt;
        $UploadDestination = $ImageFolder ."/". $NewName; 

        //Move file to location:
        if(move_uploaded_file($TmpLocation, $UploadDestination)){

            //Yay! Image was uploaded!
            //Do whatever you want here!
        }

        //File didnt upload:
        else{
            //Redirect:
            header("Location: /upload.php?e=UPLOAD_FAILED");
        }
    }

    //An error occured ?
    else{
        //Redirect:
        header("Location: /upload.php?e=UPLOAD_FAILED");
    }

}
//Filetype not allowed!
else{

    //redirect:
    header("Location: /upload.php?e=NOT_IMAGE");
}



}
else{
//No file was submitted :s send them back, eh ?
header("Location: /upload.php");
}
```

OK, i think its done now!
If you want to use your own "Look" just copy and paste the `<form></form>` stuff and maybe the simple "error" handler ?

Have a good one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input class="uploadGAConnection" #uploadFile  type="file" (change)="uploadGAConnectionDetails($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".csv,.json" (click)="uploadFile.value=null">
```

You can simply give a reference and set its value null on every click.