# Displaying Lots of Images Using One PHP File

Tags: php, image, loading, using

I hope someone will help me with this. Namely, I need a PHP code which will display images in a HTML/PHP page based on their id. For example: the file `ShowPicture.php`, and the code in it something like this:

```
PictureID = "MyPicture1"
MyPicture1_Source = "/Pictures/Picture1.jpg";
PictureID = "MyPicture2"
MyPicture2_Source = "/Pictures/Picture2.png";
PictureID = "MyPicture3"
MyPicture3_Source = "/Pictures/Picture3.gif";
PictureID = "MyPicture4"
MyPicture4_Source = "/Pictures/Picture4.bmp";
```

Example of usage on the pages:

```
HTML/PHP PAGE 1: <IMG src="ShowPicture.php?id=MyPicture4">
HTML/PHP PAGE 4: <IMG src="ShowPicture.php?id=MyPicture2">
HTML/PHP PAGE 2: <IMG src="ShowPicture.php?id=MyPicture3">
HTML/PHP PAGE 3: <IMG src="ShowPicture.php?id=MyPicture1">
```

I don't currently use any code since I didn't find good enough which will suit this particular need of mine.
The file should be something like Facebook's `rsrc.php` file, which fetches all the graphics for the site whilst hiding the real source path.

EDIT: I do not need Sessions nor Cookies, I want the pictures to be displayed permanently on pages through PHP, even after the user refreshes/reloads the pages.

EDIT 2: No (My)SQL. The PHP file itself and alone must be sort of a database for <strike>storing and</strike> displaying images.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on this question: [Gettings private files or showing private images in a HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410732/gettings-private-files-or-showing-private-images-in-a-html-page/32412736#32412736). It's not 100% the same, but you should easily be able to adept the idea to what you want. The code keeps the actual path to images 100% secure. Even if you know the direct link to the image, you won't be able to access it.

Comment: So basicly you want a secure way to display images, but you don't want to use the tools that are required for that? Well in that case, show us what you've tried yourself. Because as you know, SO is here to help with issues you have with your code. Not to do your job for you.

Comment: @icecub I have tried nothing yet due to the lack of appropriate code. I am not expecting you to do the job for me if you are not skillful enough. That's why I explained close enough what I need, if it can be achieved so.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being skilled enough or not. Basicly what you are asking is the equivalent of **I want to secure my house, but I don't want to use any doors or locks**. It's not possible. You can put guards and dogs and weapons everywhere, your house is still wide open.

Comment: It doesn't have to be **secure** way, it only has to be a way for accomplishing it. Regardless of security. Gotcha? :-)

Comment: you need masking the call for example the url page will be img.php?image=1234, on the code behind read the image and return in the response as image...

Comment: @icecub You wanted code, so here it is, but it doesn't work:
`<?php
switch($_GET['id'])
{
 case '1': $img = "img/img1.jpg";
 header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
 readfile($img);
 break;
}
?>`

And <IMG src="Picture.php?id=1"> won't display any picture.

Comment: I've written the code for you. Next time leave the attitude behind. Stack Overflow has pretty strict rules regarding what kind of questions you can ask and what is expected from you when asking. No one here is trying to be an ass to you. We're just keeping people out that are looking for a free programmer to do their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted you to put efford in it yourself. Stack Overflow is ment to help you when you have issues with your code. It's not ment for people that just want some programmer to do all the work for them. Anyway, I've taken a few minutes to do it for you now, so here it is:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET["id"];

switch($id){
    case "MyPicture1":
        $file = "img/img1.jpg";
        break;
    case "MyPicture2":
        $file = "img/img2.jpg";
        break;
    case "MyPicture3":
        $file = "img/img3.jpg";
        break;
    case "MyPicture4":
        $file = "img/img4.jpg";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Invalid ID given!";
        exit;
}

if(file_exists($file)){
    $size = getimagesize($file);
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

    if($size and $fp){
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($file)).' GMT');
        header('Content-Type: '.$size['mime']);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

        fpassthru($fp);
    }

    exit;
} else {
    echo "File not found!";
}

?>
```

You can modify it any further yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I am still a novice with PHP.

Comment: @DejanVasiljević No problem. Please click "Accept answer" next to the answer. It's a way to show your appreciation to the one that helped you out as well as making sure your question doesn't remain unanswered forever.

Comment: Of course I will, once I clarify/fix this: 
I loaded my image with <IMG src="Pictures.php?id=Lion"> and it rendered like this: http://s32.postimg.org/3pg24o5vp/2016_05_05_225424.jpg It is full path, but still won't load. If I enter the picture's full path in the URL bar, it loads normally. Now, I wonder is it a .htaccess problem or the problem in your file?

Comment: @DejanVasiljević It's probebly not a htaccess problem. Otherwise none of the images would work. It could be though that it's case sensative and you didn't notice that. Without seeing your code / server it's hard for me to guess what's going on.

Comment: Error log file:
`[06-May-2016 16:51:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Pictures.php:1) in Pictures.php on line 18

[06-May-2016 16:51:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Pictures.php:1) in Pictures.php on line 19

[06-May-2016 16:51:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Pictures.php:1) in Pictures.php on line 20`

Comment: @DejanVasiljević Make sure that you do not have _any_ whitespace before your opening `<?php` tag.