# Stop Malicious POST requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, post

I have an AJAX function that makes call to a page on my website.

```
$(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function() {
    var trigger = $(this);
    var items = trigger.attr('data-values').split('_');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mod/mypage.php",
        data : { pid : item[0], uid : item[1] },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
           if(data.job == 1) {
              // do something
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Now this works fine and do as intended. However, if I use any third-party app like **POSTMAN** and make a **POST** request to **www.xyz.com/mod/mypage.php** with parameters **pid : 1 and uid : 2**. It still goes through and make changes to my database.

> Is there anyway to check that request is generated from my
>   domain/server only?
>
> How to stop such POST requests outside from my domain?

One thing I thought was to generate a token and set in SESSION before this request and check in mypage.php that if token is set or not. Is this a feasible way?

Comment: There is something known as the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). It basicly means that your domain won't accept any POST data not coming from your own server unless you specificly allow it to with [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or in short known as CORS. This is why it's a general rule to never ever trust user input data and verify it on the serverside.

Comment: @icecub Yes but request is still going through. If I make an AJAX request from another server with explicit url 'https://www.example.com/mod/mypage.php then it is blocking via Same-origin policy but if I make a POST request from any chrome app like POSTMAN then it is going through. Why is that?

Comment: That's because those apps don't re-send the POST data. Instead they modify the POST request method before it's send in the first place. So the POST data is still coming from your server. It's simply been modified.

Comment: @icecub Is there a way to stop or check it anyhow? and I have noticed that if my script is fetching any SESSION variable value during processing then that is not fetched when request is made from such apps. Any idea?

Comment: It depends on what your script is all about. If you could explain what kind of website it is and what you're trying to achieve in more detail, I'm sure I can come up with a fitting solution

Comment: @icecub Okay. Like lets say user wants to delete a photo and clicks on delete button which contains the id of the photo. Now in JavaScript that button is the trigger and id is fetched and passed onto the PHP script via AJAX call as a POST parameter. This AJAX function is wrapped under a function which checks if user is logged in or not and depending upon that AJAX call is made. IN PHP script id is fetched $_POST['id'] and sql query is made. This is all working and in between input is also filtered and escaped.

Comment: @icecub But if the user uses an app like POSTMAN and makes a request to www.example.com/mod/deletephoto.php with parameter pid = 2 then it bypasses the login function and PHP script fetches the pid and sql query is made which I want to stop.

Comment: __You must authenticate every request server side. NEVER trust user input blindly.__

Comment: @carley how to validate request on server side? Origin, headers can be spoofed as far as I know.

Comment: Ok in that case there are 2 solutions. 1) Write a SESSION for a logged in user and check if the session exists on your PHP file. If not, simply redirect to login. 2) I assume the user is only allowed to delete his / her pictures and you have the names / locations or whatever of those pics saved in the database. Simply check the session with the user in the database and if the pic the user is trying to delete belongs to that user before actually deleting.

Comment: Users must login somehow, store the user ID in $_SESSION or whatever. On delete request, fetch the photo owner from the database. If the photo owner is the same as the logged in owner, they obviously have permission to delete. Check my answer below for how to ensure the user actually requested the delete (CSRF).

Comment: On a side note: If you're working with user images etc, you might want to read my answer on this question: [Gettings private files or showing private images in a HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410732/gettings-private-files-or-showing-private-images-in-a-html-page/32412736#32412736). It's probebly not exactly what you want, but you'll find it a very interesting read if you want to work securily with user submitted images etc :)

Comment: @icecub I am storing user ID in $_SESSION and checking them too(at least now). However, there are cases like when the site admin wants to change the status of a record. Let's say from is_active 1 to 0. Now in the AJAX request two parameters are passed record_id = a and status = b. Now if POSTMAN makes a request to example.com/mod/changeStatus with above parameters then it is going through. What should I do now? Check if admin session is set or not in PHP script?

Comment: @Carey read my above comment.

Comment: You don't need an extra session for admins. Basicly what you do is check if the user session has admin privilages in the database before performing the action. That's all

Comment: What icecub said, before performing any action check that the user __actually has the permissions to perform the action__. On login, check if admin, set `$_SESSION['admin'] = true` is a possible way to do it.

Comment: @icecub so in my PHP script I need to fetch user ID from SESSION. Check if it is empty or not. If empty then error else proceed. I am not checking permissions as only admins can login in to admin panel so it is assumed that they have permissions. My current change status script takes two parameters and if I make request from POSTMAN with those parameters then it is going through so I need to modify my script and check SESSION. right? P.S. admins and users have two different sessions as of now.

Comment: @Carey See above comment please.

Comment: If you check for admin session, it should be good enough for now.

Comment: I'm afraid the amount of comments on your question is getting a bit to much now. I'd suggest you click on my name and browse towards my profile. You'll find my email address there. If you mail me, I can send you some details to start a chat session so I might be able to help you out in more detail :)

Comment: @icecub Okay. I will. Thank you for the help though :D

Comment: @Carey Thank you for the help!
P.S. I have a function which I can access via Login::restrictFront() and Login::restrictAdmin which checks if the user or admin is logged in or not so I am putting that in top of my all /mod/scripts so it checks the user on server side too and if not logged in then shows error. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: If you've solved your problem mark an answer below as solved so people know this question is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what a CSRF token is for. Users must navigate to the page first, which generates a token to submit, ergo without navigating to the page will render any POST requests invalid.

However, trying to stop someone from POST'ing a request to your endpoint from a utility like POSTman is an exercise in futility. You must **authenticate** every request to the endpoint, in this case just check the photo id is owned by the submitting client.

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) provides a decent description of what a CSRF is:

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they're currently authenticated. CSRF attacks specifically target state-changing requests, not theft of data, since the attacker has no way to see the response to the forged request.

#### Example validation flow

**Login.php**

```
<?php

// Establish DB connection, validate

$_SESSION['id'] = $db->getUserId();
$_SESSION['admin'] = $db->getAdminStatus();
```

**Delete.php**

```
<?php

if (!$db->isPhotoOwner($_POST['pid'])) {
    exit;
}

// Delete photo flow
```

**Admin.php**

```
<?php

if (!$_SESSION['admin']) {
    die("Not admin.");
}

// Do admin action or whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have the calling page identify itself with $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] and write that value to a hidden input field or $_POST and check for it at the beginning of processing.  Any confirmed value you choose might work.

If they are already imitating the data of your JSON, then maybe drop it into the javascript with PHP dynamically writing the code value on page serving.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can have hidden inputs all you want. They can still be seen in the POST request and page source and easily copied / modified. Only data that can't be touched by the user can be trusted. Like a SESSION for example.

Comment: If trust is an issue, then AJAX is inappropriate for the situation altogether.  Confirmed state changes for security would be synchronized, not AJAX.